# django two foreign key for same model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

*my model*

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    CreatedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Oluşturulma Tarihi")
    ModifiedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="Son Güncellenme tarihi")
    Isdeleted = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Silindi", default=False)

class Case(BaseModel):
    CaseNumber = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    Customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    Title = models.ForeignKey(CaseTitle)
    CaseCategory = models.ForeignKey(CaseCategory, verbose_name="Kategori")
    Priority = models.ForeignKey(CasePriority)
    Status = models.ForeignKey(CaseStatus)
    Detail = models.TextField()
    Group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='User' )
    AssignedUser = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='AssignedUser')
    CloseDetail = models.TextField blank=True)
```

i just want to give 2 foreign key this my model but error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 796, in __init__
    to._meta.model_name AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute '_meta'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute
    django.setup()   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked  
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module   
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed   
File "/code/Case/models.py", line 91, in <module>
    class Case(BaseModel):   
File "/code/Case/models.py", line 101, in Case
    AssignedUser = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='AssignedUser')   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 802, in __init__
    RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT, AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey>) is invalid.
First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

Comment: show full models code and more details for error stack

Comment: question editted

Comment: but my base model already have models.Model
 

class BaseModel(models.Model):

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're redefining `User` The relevant section of Django code this is bombing on is an `isinstance(to, str)` which means `User` is not a model but it's also not a string (it's a `ForeignKey`).

If you're using Django's User model or a customized variant the correct way to obtain a reference independently is to use `django.contrib.auth.get_user_model()`. e.g.:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In Python it's convention to lowercase names unless they are classes.

Comment: thank you so much i did your suggest and it works thanks a lot

Comment: That's not what solved the problem, just changing the property from `User` to `user` solved it. In fact all properties should be lowercase to avoid conflicts with class names.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you only implement one relationship to the model `User`? The error message:

```
First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

lets me assume, that you're not passing the actual class of the `User` model. How do you obtain it?

Also, from looking at the fields of `BaseModel` I suppose, it could be an abstract base model:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    CreatedDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Oluşturulma Tarihi")
    ...
```

See here for more information: https://godjango.com/blog/django-abstract-base-class-model-inheritance/

Comment: its coming from here "from django.contrib.auth.models import User"

Comment: don't use camelcase for properties, `CreatedDate` is just wrong and will lead to errors down the road. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be following the python conventions on how to use uppercase, lowercase, otherwise the interpreter is going to refer to wrong variables:

- Classes are the only things that should be camel-case (`class User`, `class CaseTitle`).
- Your class properties (instance variables) should be lowercase with underscores: `case_number, user, assigned_user, etc...`

When you write `User = ForeignKey(User)` you're actually redefining the `User` variable, so in the next line `AssignedUser = ForeignKey(User)`, `User` isn't the `User` model class anymore. If I write it out, I get:

```
AssignedUser = models.ForeignKey( # User
    models.ForeignKey(  # User
        models.ForeignKey(  # User etc...
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the field name User to anything you want. It conflicts that's why you get the error.

```
class Case(BaseModel):
    ....
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='user' )
    assigned_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='assigned_user')
```

Comment: Don't use uppercase for properties, then you wouldn't get these types of errors. You shouldn't suggest to use plural just because it doesn't conflict, it makes the code unreadable (it should be singular). Use `user`, `assigned_user` and `close_detail` with `related_name`s `user` and `assigned_user`. It really really bad practice to use camel casing if it's not a class name.

Comment: I know but I just followed the ques...You can edit the ans or suggest me to edit.